# Mock Directory.GetDirectories(path) using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am writing unit tests using Moq framework in C#. However, when I try to mock the following method, I get the error: Could not find a part of the path.

```
var fileMethodsMock = new Mock<IFileMethods>();
fileMethodsMock.Setup(x => x.GetAllDirectories(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(allDirectories);
```

`GetAllDirectories` implements the `Directory.GetDirectories(path)` method and `allDirectories` is an array of directories to be returned.

Since I am writing unit tests, I am using the mock setup statement to set up the response to be returned. I do not want the method to check the actual directory etc. Please advise.

Comment: You’ll have to write a facade or use one from nuget

Comment: The posted code only contains mocking of an interface. This should not be throwing that exception. Could you provide a complete [mre]?